# Upload image from Bitmap to server as png

Tags: c#, winforms, png

I am trying to upload a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` variable I have in my C# winform application as a `.png` image on my server. Right now I know how to save a `Bitmap` as a `.png` file and then upload it to my server.

```
//Save bitmap variable as .png
bitmap.Save("img_1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

And then upload that to my server like so:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTP_username",
        "FTP_password");
    client.UploadFile("ftp://100.100.100.100/new_folder/img_1.png",
        "img_1.png");
}
```

How could I upload the `Bitmap bitmap` variable as a `.png` file on my server directly, without having to save it as a new `.png` file locally first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the `Bitmap` to a stream and upload the stream:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FTP_username", "FTP_password");
    client.UploadData("ftp://100.100.100.100/new_folder/img_1.png", ms.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Drawing;

Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(file.InputStream);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    // use the memory stream to base64 encode..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, due to the fact that the method is `UploadFile`, taking the URL of the file as a `String` as the second parameter.

What I would suggest so the user doesn't see the PNG file if they don't have to...

1. Add a method that can generate and store a random string (like the one below) as a variable private to the class.
2. Make your folder to save to this, where %TEMP% is the user's temporary folder and RandString is the random string from earlier: `%TEMP%\RandString\ImageName.jpg`
3. Save the file there and upload it.
4. When you're done, delete the folder `%TEMP%\RandString\`.

Comment: it seems that its possible. I made it work with @donboitnott answer